# How to say if something equals to a string in Sightly?

Tags: sightly

In Sightly, I want to have if statement as in below

```
if x == "Australia"
then

execute the html below
```

I am looking for some tutorial on how to do this or some example. This may not be worth asking here. However, please, may I have an example like that? I am stuck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
<div data-sly-test="${x == 'Australia'}">
    HTML about Australia
</div>
```

Here are some tutorials as well:

http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/sightly-intro-part-1/

Comment: I guess the comparision is case sensitive, is there any way where in we can make the comparision case insensitive.

Comment: @YAMAN unfortunately HTL doesn't support that. We need to use Use-Class to implement or extend that functionality. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/use-api-java.html

Comment: Thanks @khakiout, I will go with case insensitive approach for now, to cater to my current urgency.